# changed promotion extension are persistent in the basket but not in orders

Tags: shopware, shopware6

i made a plugin, where i extend the promotions with some text, image, whatsoever, that are persistent, when i have the promotion in the basket.

i change some stuff in the promotion and it stays the same as before in the basket. only if i remove the promotion and add it again, the changes are there. that is what i expect it to be.

in orders, when i change the same stuff in the promotion, these changes are not persistent. in the orders it always shows the last edited promotion version. thats not what i expect. once the customer hast bought something with that promotion, the things i change should not have any effect.

do i have to change/extend the orders in some kind, to make it persistend there too?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide some lines of code I can only guess. I assume what you mean is the changes you apply on the fly during the checkout shouldn't be applied when editing an already placed order. Also assuming that you created your own cart processor to apply these changes, you can check the behavior for the permission whether promotions should be skipped. See the [`PromotionProcessor`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/0bc4296f58d8937271e606b31641a7f7f9db6b99/src/Core/Checkout/Promotion/Cart/PromotionProcessor.php#L49) for reference. When editing placed orders, the permission to skip re-processing promotions should be set.

```php
public function process(CartDataCollection $data, Cart $original, Cart $toCalculate, SalesChannelContext $context, CartBehavior $behavior): void
{
    if ($behavior->hasPermission(self::SKIP_PROMOTION)) {
        return;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```